# The difference between "Ereignis" and "Eventuell"

Tags: meaning, difference, meaning-in-context, heidegger

I know that this two words *Ereignis* and *eventuell* are related, but I would like to know more about what makes them different.

Translating them into my native language, Portuguese, they both translate into "evento," which translates roughly into "event" in English.

And, if possible, I would like to know the meaning-in-context using Heidegger.

Comment: *Ereignis* is a noun, meaning event. *Eventuell* is an adjective or adverb, meaning *possible* or *possibly*, respectively. A dictionary had told you. So, what was your question again?

Comment: I see you are new here, so, welcome. Second, and most important, you *must* look up that words in a dictionary before asking here. (I'd link here the meta discussion to *questions about differences*, but the meta is now unaccessible).

Comment: I looked in a dictionary and I think the problem is in translating to portugese or in portuguese itself.
I got the information here that both means 'evento' (event) and only it. 
But one I use as 'acontecimento' (happening - Ereignis) and was wondering how to make the difference.
Maybe could I use Vorkommen?

Comment: @Gail "Vorkommen" would be "occurance". Can you eventuell give some context/examples of usage?

Comment: Both words are completely different in German. No German would ever even so much as get the idea to draw a connection. Em1 has given you the translations. Why would you want to use a different word? Just because they're the same in Portuguese doesn't mean they're the same in a different language.

Comment: "eventuell" is an adjective or adverb. Maybe Heidegger used the word in a new sense and as a noun in his philosophical writings, but that would be Heidegger's individual use, it is not usual in standard language to use "eventuell" as a noun.

Comment: The OP has an unusual problem insofar as Portuguese, not English, is her native language. She appears to have a valid concern insofar as something has been lost in the DOUBLE translation, first into Portuguese, then into English. After I edited the question to articulate this concern, I was wondering if the question can be reopened.

Comment: Nice edit @TomAu - this makes the question much much clearer now :)

Comment: @TomAu Do both really translate to *evento*? I thought *eventual* was *eventuell* and *evento* was *Ereignis*.

Comment: @c.p.: I was just using the OP's comment (third from the top), and "cut and paste" it in the question.

Comment: @TomAu I see. As hispanic, I recognize Portuguese as quite isomorphic to my language, whence it's quite surprising that *evento* would be not only a noun but and adverb too. And a pair of dictionaries had already confirmed my suspicion. So, I'll ask directly the OP, why did (s)he state that.

Comment: Gali, could you please link to a dictionary where *evento* (in Portuguese) has an adverbial meaning? I haven't found it. Some people are trying to  help answering your question; it would be problematic if you provided wrong information.

Answer (score 6):

To sum up the confusing comments and semi-answer:

The two words *eventuell* and *Ereignis* are NOT (semantically) related.

*Das Ereignis* is a noun and can be translated as *the event*, while *eventuell* is an adverb and can be translated as *maybe*, *perhaps*, *possible*, etc.

*Eventuell gehe ich heute Abend zum Fußball spielen.* -> *Maybe I will go play soccer tonight.*

*Ich weiß nicht, ob dieses Ereignis eintreten wird.* -> *I don't know if this event will happen.*

I don't speak Portugese and I don't know which translator or dictionary you used to look up these two words, but the [first online translator I found](http://en.bab.la/dictionary/german-portuguese/) translates *evento* correctly into *Ereignis*. Translating *eventuell* yields *por acaso* or *possivelmente*.

Comment: Die Worte haben im Deutschen zwar eine völlig unterschiedliche Bedeutung, sind aber etymologisch verwandt. [Zitat](https://www.dwds.de/wb/eventuell):  eventuell Adj. ‘möglich, unter Umständen eintretend’ (nur attributiv), häufig Adv. ‘vielleicht, möglicherweise, unter Umständen’. Zu lat. ēventus ‘Ausgang, Erfolg, Ereignis’ (dieses von lat. ēvenīre ‘hervorkommen, enden, sich ereignen’, einer Präfixbildung zum Verb lat. venīre ‘kommen’) wird in der Kanzleisprache ein Adjektiv nlat. eventualis ‘zufällig, möglich’ geprägt, das Anfang des 18. Jhs. zu eventual eingedeutscht wird.

Comment: Ende 18. Jhs. tritt diese Form hinter eventuell zurück, einer Entlehnung von frz. éventuel ‘etwaig, möglich, zufällig’, das ebenfalls nlat. eventualis voraussetzt. Als Adverb kommt bereits im 17. Jh. die Bildung nlat. eventualiter in dt. Texten vor; sie ist noch im ausgehenden 19. Jh. durchaus gebräuchlich, doch findet sich von der Mitte des 19. Jhs. an auch adverbielle Verwendung von eventuell. Eventualität f. ‘möglicherweise eintretender Fall’ (19. Jh.), nach gleichbed. frz. éventualité, aber mit in Analogie zu ursprünglich lat. Substantiven umgebildeter Endung;

Comment: jetzt oft im Plur. alle Eventualitäten üblich.